# Insert and Update in SQL Using User-Defined Table Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Following is new data type that I created.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UpdateHotelTableType] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [HotelID] [int] NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,

)
```

Following is my stored procedure that I used the above datatype.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Hotel_Info_Update]
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @XHotelInfoDetails UpdateHotelTableType READONLY,

AS
BEGIN

    Update dbo.HotelInfo
    SET 
    FromDate = r.FromDate,
    from @XHotelInfoDetails r
    Where HotelInfo.ID = r.ID

END
```

This is working fine for update results in database. But I want to check whether the id is exists and if the id is not exists insert the row in to the table. otherwise update current record. In here I am sending the list of data for update.

Can any one help me to recreate the stored procedure to insert the data too by checking the existence of ID.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql):

> **Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table.** For example, you can synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one table based on differences found in the other table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Hotel_Info_Update]
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @XHotelInfoDetails UpdateHotelTableType READONLY,

AS
BEGIN

    MERGE dbo.HotelInfo AS trg
    USING @XHotelInfoDetails AS src
      ON src.ID = trg.ID
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET FromDate = src.FromDate
     WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT (col1, col2, ...)
       VALUES (src.col1, src.col2, ...);
END
```

**EDIT:**

> In my datatable, there can be newly added rows as well as deleted rows. So how can I compare the id and delete rows from hotelinfo table?

You could add new clause:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
     THEN DELETE;
```

with specific condition to delete data from target.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. Yes it seems working. I just want to know how to delete rows using this scenario? In my datatable, there can be newly added rows as well as deleted rows. So how can I compare the id and delete rows from hotelinfo table?

Comment: @KateFernando Please see my edited answer. If it is insufficient I strognly recommend to ask new question and post sample data/desired output.

Comment: Merge is a good Idea, but as i know and with my experience only for Insert and Update, with Delete clause there's a bad performance that making the query slow.

Comment: @Lukaasz Szozda I know this is old post but how is the primary key which is an identity key in the destination table handled as in how do I not pass the id parameter when it needs to insert?  I've got the update working but on insert, when I get to my new row (created in gridview) the insert fails because the id column is specified (and obviously not needed on an insert).  It's an int data type so I tried zero but still no love.

Comment: @Doreen  I am not sure if I understand your question. If the target table has PK defined as identity at the merge part the PK column `ID` should not be specified at all. In the answer ` WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT (col1, col2, ...)
       VALUES (src.col1, src.col2, ...);` the column list contains only non-key columns, `ID` is used to identify new vs existing rows

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda The  MERGE sp works for the update.  In C# code the ID column (in gridview row) has a value which is passed as a parameter when it's going to be an UPDATE.  When it’s a new row (added to grid dynamically) the value being passed is "&nbsp” &throws error "Input string is not in the correct format" it s/b an Integer. What value should I pass as the ID column/parameter when it's an insert?   I don't know what to pass to the ID when the row needs to be INSERTed. My datatable in the .net code contains the ID column, should it be removed even though the UDT contains that column?

Comment: @Doreen If you have control over MERGE statement, simply skip the `ID` column from both INSERT(column list) and VALUES part: `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT (col1, col2, ...)
       VALUES (src.col1, src.col2, ...);`  -> (col1, col2, ...) includes all non-key column, here id is skipped

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda yes, I understand the INSERT syntax and I have done as you suggested in the SQL MERGE statement.  The problem me> is on the c# coding side.  I have to pass a value to the ID column because it’s needed for an UPDATE but when it’s an INSERT, the code requires a valid integer which doesn’t allow NULL.  How do I pass a NULL value to ID even though it won’t be used during the INSERT?  I’m probably missing something very simple.  Maybe it needs to be a string not an int?

Comment: @Doreen It looks more like a C# mapping of SQL UDF type case. Could you try to use [nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) int? or provide value that is outside IDENTITY allowed values (for instance IDENTITY(1,1) -> `-1`)?

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda  I used an identity value outside the bounds as you suggested (-1) and it worked but only for the first INSERT.  Subsequent inserts throw error "Cannot insert duplicate key in UDT object.  Is it possible to clear the ID in the UDT after the insert? The new ID in the table was assigned the next number as expected. Gosh.  I am so close. :)

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda I think I resolved the issue thanks to your help!  I removed the primary key in the UDT completely and the inserts seem to be working.

Answer (score 8):

You can Simply do 2 Queries:
1. "*Update*" command
2. "*Insert*" command.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Hotel_Info_Update]
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @XHotelInfoDetails UpdateHotelTableType READONLY,

AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.HotelInfo
    SET FromDate = r.FromDate,
    FROM dbo.HotelInfo 
    JOIN @XHotelInfoDetails X ON X.Id = HotelInfo.Id

    INSERT INTO dbo.HotelInfo (Col1,Col2)
    SELECT X.Col1,
           X.Col2
    FROM @XHotelInfoDetails X
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                   (
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM dbo.HotelInfo InnerTable
                     WHERE X.Id = InnerTable.Id
                   )

END
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply.  I just want to know how to delete rows using this scenario? In my datatable, there can be newly added rows as well as deleted rows. So how can I compare the id and delete rows from hotelinfo table?

Comment: hey @KateFernando, your UDT type are storing all of your data that existing in your "HotelInfo" table? ? if yes, you can simply add delete clause after update and delete clauses, and write in the where clause if there's an items that exists in your table and doesn't exists in your UDT.